# Pros and cons of installing php 5.6 and mysql 5.6 on debian 7 wheezy

Tags: linux, mysql, php, debian, debian-wheezy

I was setting up a VPS server for my client and we had talked that I would install the last stable versions of the programs. Now, in Debian 7 wheezy by default php 5.4 and mysql 5.5 are available. I am aware of how to upgrade to php 5.6 and mysql 5.6, but the question is - as it is not available from debian's official packages is it recommended to upgrade? what are the pros and cons of doing so? are there any security issues that might appear from upgrading ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The safety of upgrading depends on who is providing the upgraded patches. With the defaults on Debian stable, there is a security team that ensures all major security fixes get backported to those versions. If you install from a third party repo, you are trusting them, rather than the Debian Security Team to provide these patches. It is a possibility you will need to upgrade to a new version of PHP or MySQL (instead of the same version with backported security patches) to continue security support if you decided to go with 3rd party repositories.